# How to read vimeo API response?

Tags: json, vimeo-api

I am playing around with Vimeo APIs. I fetch all folders(projects) using

```
$options= array();    
$response = $client->request('/me/folders?page=2&perPage=3', $options, 'GET');
```

It returns a reponse, 'https://pastebin.com/WnjyX72D' which is not recognizable by any json formatting tool. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the response is probably a json. it looks like you printed the $response object. the content you're seeing looks like a string representation of a PHP object. trying calling this API from an HTTP client like postman, insomnia, etc..